# clearTimeout() returning TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearTimeout' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'll start by saying I have no idea what I'm doing... lesson learned.

I'm stuck on what should be a simple coding problem. This program (Foundry VTT) has a bunch of add on modules and one of them is a time module (https://gitlab.com/tposney/about-time), lets you do things at certain intervals.
I was playing around with it and set a notification at every 1 second interval... now I can't turn it off.

I created a macro using the .reminderEvery() function

> reminderEvery({minutes: 10}, "Check for wandering monsters"}
> do a reminder every 10 minutes.
> Each of the above return an id which can be used to cancel the event

and in the readme there is a function to cancel the recurring event

> clearTimeout(eventID)

I have looked through the console and found the uid that corresponds to the macro I created, now I'm trying to create a new macro to run clearTimeout(). Here's my code and here's the error:

```js
var uid1 = 1601297881331;
var uid2 = 1601298513496;
game.gameTime.clearTimeout(uid1);
game.gameTime.clearTimeout(uid2);
```

```html
Macros.js:224 TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearTimeout' of undefined
    at Macro.eval (eval at callScriptMacroFunction (Macros.js:176), <anonymous>:7:15)
    at Macro.callScriptMacroFunction [as callScriptFunction] (Macros.js:179)
    at Macro.renderMacro [as renderContent] (Macros.js:197)
    at Macro.executeMacro (Macros.js:221)
    at MacroConfig._onExecute (foundry.js:18885)
```

Comment: Hi @HoodWolf ..

Comment: what is `gameTime`?

Comment: According to the [API](https://gitlab.com/tposney/about-time#about-time), it's supposed to be `game.Gametime` instead of `game.gameTime`

Comment: you have to store value add setTimeout inside 1 variable then you can clear the value